# How to concatenate an empty array with Numpy.concatenate?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, concatenation

I need to create an array of a specific size `mxn` filled with empty values so that when I `concatenate` to that array the initial values will be overwritten with the added values.

My current code:

```
a = numpy.empty([2,2])  # Make empty 2x2 matrix
b = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])    # Make example 2x2 matrix
myArray = numpy.concatenate((a,b))    # Combine empty and example arrays
```

Unfortunately, I end up making a `4x2` matrix instead of a `2x2` matrix with the values of b.

Is there anyway to make an actually empty array of a certain size so when I concatenate to it, the values of it become my added values instead of the default + added values?

Comment: Why not just do `a[:]=b`?  Or `a=b.copy()`?  Do you want to keep any initial elements of `a` after this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Oniow said, concatenate does exactly what you saw.

If you want 'default values' that will differ from regular scalar elements, I would suggest you to initialize your array with NaNs (as your 'default value'). If I understand your question, you want to merge matrices so that regular scalars will override your 'default value' elements.

Anyway I suggest you to add the following:

```
def get_default(size_x,size_y):
    # returns a new matrix filled with 'default values'
    tmp = np.empty([size_x,size_y])
    tmp.fill(np.nan)
    return tmp
```

And also:

```
def merge(a, b):
    l = lambda x, y: y if np.isnan(x) else x
    l = np.vectorize(l)
    return map(l, a, b)
```

Note that if you merge 2 matrices, and both values are non 'default' then it will take the value of the left matrix.

Using NaNs as default value, will result the expected behavior from a default value, for example all math ops will result 'default' as this value indicates that you don't really care about this index in the matrix.

Comment: Be ware of 2 things - `np.nan` is a float, so this is a good thing to do with `dtype=int` arrays.  And your `vectorize` operation is almost as slow as plain iteration over all elements (at most a 2x speedup).  It will be much slower than `tmp[:]=b`, especially for large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly - concatenate is not what you are looking for. Concatenate does as you saw: joins [along an axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

If you are trying to have an empty matrix that becomes the values of another you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([2,2])
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

my_array = a + b
```

--or--

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.zeros([2,2]) # you can use empty here instead in this case.

my_array[0,0] = float(input('Enter first value: ')) # However you get your data to put them into the arrays.
```

But, I am guessing that is not what you really want as you could just use `my_array = b`. If you edit your question with more info I may be able to help more.

If you are worried about values adding over time to your array...

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([2,2])

my_array = b # b is some other 2x2 matrix
''' Do stuff '''
new_b # New array has appeared
my_array = new_b # update your array to these new values. values will not add. 

# Note: if you make changes to my_array those changes will carry onto new_b. To avoid this at the cost of some memory:
my_array = np.copy(new_b)
```